# Jquery - Seleccionar item "superior"

Tags: php, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

tengo una lista de elementos que tienen esta estructura

```
<ol class="ui-sortable">   
<li class="action-element ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle newClass" data-id="photoType">
      <div data-id="1" class="element boxElementPicture">
         <div style="float: right"><i class="fas fa-trash btnDeleteItem" data-type="btnImgPhoto" id="1" data-id="1" style=""></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-th-list btnOptionsItem" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo" style=""></i></div>
         <div><span class="titleField" "="">Campo de Foto</span><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Titulo..." class="title"><br> 
        <input type="checkbox" class="chbRequired"><br>
       <span class="requiredField">&nbsp;Campo requerido</span></div>
   </div>
 </li>
 </ol>
```

Esto visualmente genera una caja de texto con un botón de eliminar que tiene el atributo data-id, que luego uso para lanzar un modal de boostrap y preguntar al usuario si quiere borrar el elemento o no.

El código que realiza esto es este

```
        $(document).on('click', '.btnModalDeleteItem', function(event) {
            var id = $('.btnDeleteItem').attr('data-id');
            $('#deleteModal').attr('data-id',id);
            $('.element').filter('[data-id='+id+']').remove();
            $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
    });
```

Con este código lo que hago es pasar el attributo data-id del botón para poder capturarlo en el botón del modal (botón de borrar) y al hacer click en dicho botón borrar el elemento.

Como vereis el elemento html que muestro al principio de todo es un "li" y yo tengo el data-id del elemento "inferior" el div con la clase boxElementPicture

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema lo tengo que con esta instrucción borro el elemento "div" pero me dejo el "li" vacio , la pregunta es como a partir del "div" borrar desde el elemento superior el "li"

La instrucción tal como pongo anteriormente es esta

```
   $('.element').filter('[data-id='+id+']').remove();
```

Respondiendo al compañero @cooper

La solución que me has propuesto hace lo mismo que el código que tengo yo , borra el elemento div , es decir esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el elemento que necesito borrar es el elemento superior a este div
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo pasandole al método *filter* una función anónima que obtenga el elemento con el *data-id* que te interesa:

```js
var id = 2;
$('.element').filter(function(){
  return $(this).attr('data-id') == id;
}).remove();
```

```css
li {
list-style-type:none;
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
<li class="element" data-id="1">elm 1</li>
<li class="element" data-id="2">elm 2</li>
<li class="element" data-id="3">elm 3</li>
<li class="element" data-id="4">elm 4</li>
</ol>
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Si lo que necesitas es borrar el elemento padre, puedes hacerlo con el método *closest*. Este método permite obtener el primer elemento "padre" con el selector que le pases. Así pues, sabiendo que el elemento padre del elemento div que has capturado es un elemento *li* con clase *action-element*, puedes hacer:

Capturas el div;

```
var id = 2;

var div =  $('.element').filter(function(){
  return $(this).attr('data-id') == id;
});
```

Y ahora eliminas el elemento padre:

```
div.closest('.action-element').remove();
```

También lo puedes hacer todo "de golpe":

```
$('.element').filter(function(){
  return $(this).attr('data-id') == id;
}).closest('.action-element').remove();
```

Comment: Gracias @cooper , te he respondido en el primer post, el problema que tengo que necesito subir un "elemento" más que el div, necesito cojer el li

Comment: @ilernet, respuesta actualizada.

Comment: muchas gracias, problema solucionado. 1000 gracias